# Does ToString("F") lose precision relative to ToString("G")?

Tags: c#, .net, numbers, format, tostring

I'm programming in C# using .Net 3.5, trying to control the format in which floats are output as strings.

However, I'm seeing some unexpected behaviour. <strike>If my code contains (for example):</strike>

float value = 50.8836975;

**Edit**  Sorry, that (deleted) code "sample" was unhelpful. Basically, my question was seeking to explain the results of my debugging statements below when I set a breakpoint after "value" - a C# float - had been assigned the result of a calculation. [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet)'s answer is exactly what I needed (his first line takes me to task for the unhelpful code).

Then I see the following results when I try various options in my **Immediate** window:

```
?value
50.8836975
?value.ToString("G9")
"50.8836975"
?value.ToString("F9")
"50.883700000"
```

Can anyone explain why my F9-formatted value seems to have lost 3 digits of precision?

Comment: `50.8836975.ToString("F9")` -> `50.883697500` for me (note that the value is a `double`, not a `float`).

Comment: Your code won't compile to start with - you've given a `double` literal and tried to assign it to a `float` variable. Which is it?

Comment: OK, I'll come clean. My code didn't actually contain that line value=50.8836975. However, that was the value shown in my debugger for that float (yes, really!) variable when I hit my breakpoint. So I'll have to defer that one to Visual Studio.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your question is unclear because you've given a real value without an `f` suffix, and tried to assign it to a `float` variable. If you're actually using a `float` variable, then the *exact* value is

```
50.883697509765625
```

If you're actually using a `double` variable, then the exact value is:

```
50.8836974999999966939867590554058551788330078125
```

I get the same results as you for F9 *if* you use a `float`, but not if you use a `double`.

The reason for the reduced precision is revealed by the documentation for [`System.Single`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.single.aspx) (`float`):

> By default, a Single value contains only 7 decimal digits of precision, although a maximum of 9 digits is maintained internally.

I believe `F` is correctly displaying all of the *real* digits of precision, in an attempt to prevent you from believing that you've actually got more information than you have.